# Android grant read/write URI permission and file URI

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

Where exactly in official docs is stated, that `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` is intended only for `ContentProvider` URI and don't works on simple file URI?

I have read in different unofficial sources, that `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` is not working on simple file URI. An example of simple file URI would be an URI constructed by `Uri.fromFile(someFile)`. As I understood, granting URI permissions works only for `ContentProvider` URI. But I can't find in official docs any information related to this behavior of URI permission granting system.

And additional question. Implementing `FileProvider` seems like only reliable way of sharing files to other apps?

Comment: "Where exactly in official docs is stated, that FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION is intended only for ContentProvider URI and don't works on simple file URI?" -- I doubt that this is covered in the docs. "Implementing FileProvider seems like only reliable way of sharing files to other apps?" -- you need to strongly consider using a `ContentProvider`, whether that is `FileProvider` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading I found couple statements in [official trainings](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html):

> While URI permissions don’t work on file:// URIs as is generated by
>   Uri.fromFile(), they do work on Uris associated with Content
>   Providers. Rather than implement your own just for this, you can and
>   should use FileProvider as explained in File Sharing.